# How to change each value in JS object using Lodash

Tags: lodash

I have an object like:

```
{ 
  home: 78,
  draw: 81,
  away: 36,
  u0_5: 16,
  o0_5: 26,
  u1_5: 10,
  o1_5: 68,
  u2_5: 48,
  o2_5: 50,
  u3_5: 29,
  o3_5: 31,
  u4_5: 50,
  o4_5: 5,
  u5_5: 68,
  o5_5: 56
}
```

my goal is to get new same structure object, but with each value multiplied by 100 and get the same structure.

```
 { 
   home: 7800,
   draw: 8100,
   away: 3600,
   ...
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mapValues()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mapValues) to solve this problem, together with a callback to transform each value.

```
const result = _.mapValues(data, v => v * 100);
```

```js
const data = { 
  home: 78,
  draw: 81,
  away: 36,
  u0_5: 16,
  o0_5: 26,
  u1_5: 10,
  o1_5: 68,
  u2_5: 48,
  o2_5: 50,
  u3_5: 29,
  o3_5: 31,
  u4_5: 50,
  o4_5: 5,
  u5_5: 68,
  o5_5: 56
};

const result = _.mapValues(data, v => v * 100);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0!important}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

With [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) you can create a function with `_.mapValues()` and `_.multiply()` that iterates the object, and multiplies each value by 100:

```js
const fn = _.mapValues(_.multiply(100))

const obj = {"home":78,"draw":81,"away":36,"u0_5":16,"o0_5":26,"u1_5":10,"o1_5":68,"u2_5":48,"o2_5":50,"u3_5":29,"o3_5":31,"u4_5":50,"o4_5":5,"u5_5":68,"o5_5":56}

const result = fn(obj)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
       data.key = value*100;
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.